# How can I format the summary value in ngx-datatable with summaryFunc/ summaryTemplate?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I implemented ngx-datatable in my angular project and I need to display the summary row for my table.
Base on the document, I used [summaryFunc] and the summary value is showing correctly.
But now I need to format this value.
For example: 1,000 USD instead of 1000.

How can I do that with[summaryFunc] ?

- [summaryFunc] = "sampleFunc | number" => not working, it say result of sampleFunc not a number (I also returned number inside sampleFunc).
- I tried to use DecimalPipe inside sampleFunc => not working, because inside sampleFunc everything is undefined (this and all pipe...).
- I also tried to use [summaryTemplate]="sampleTemplate". samplateTempate is defined by ng-template. But I dont know how to passing the summary value into sampleTemplate?

```html
<ngx-datatable
            #table
            class="material"
            [headerHeight]="40"
            [footerHeight]="40"
            [columnMode]="'flex'"
            [rowHeight]="'auto'"
            [summaryRow]="hasSummaryRow"
            [summaryHeight]="45"
            (resize)="onResize($event)"
            (reorder)="onReorder($event)"
            (activate)="onActive($event)"
            [loadingIndicator]="!items"
            [limit]="pageItems"
            [rows]="items"
            [count]="totalItems"
            [externalPaging]="externalPaging"
            [offset]="offset"
            (page)="onPaging($event)">
      <ngx-datatable-column *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns; let i=index"
                                  [name]="col.value"
                                  [flexGrow]="calculateWidth(col)"
                                  [sortable]="!col.columnType"
                                  [canAutoResize]="true"
                                  [resizeable]="!col.columnType"
                                  [summaryFunc]="sampleFunc"
                                  [summaryTemplate]="sampleTemplate">
      </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>
<ng-template #sampleTemplate let-value="value">
        <span>{{value|number}}</span>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I my self found the answer for this... Inside the summaryFunc I just need to declare new pipe to format the number.

- First, we create new custom pipe to format the number base on your requirement. Refer to this post https://medium.com/better-programming/creating-a-custom-pipe-for-your-angular-app-64b419a93f2a.
- Second, inside summaryFunc, we create new instand of custom pipe by `const customePipe = new CustomPipe();`
- Finnaly, we format the value by transform method of customePipe by call `customPipe.transform(value);`